# Rock and roll past

Tags: grammar

According to Wikipedia, Jerry Lee Lewis's successes continued throughout the decade and he embraced his rock and roll past with songs such as a cover of the Big Bopper's "Chantilly Lace" and Mack Vickery's "Rockin' My Life Away". Is "rock and roll" used as an adjective in this context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just not about English language.

Comment: Asking if a terminology is an adjective or not is not about the Enligsh language? I am sorry if that's the case.

Comment: I'm sorry, Maurice, I misread. Yes, a noun can be used as an adjective. It is then called a [noun-modifier or attributive noun or noun-adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Mitch :)